# Exercise a stock option in a US-based company as a non US tax resident

Tags: united-states, taxes, employee-stock-options, option-exercise

I'm given 1000 stock options (all vested) at $100 strike price per option. Current stock valuation is $1000 per share. As I understand, if I exercise I'll pay $100K out of my pocket and I'll also get taxed on $900K capital gain (please correct me if I'm wrong here).
I'm not a US citizen, but I work full-time in the USA now (resident alien), my employment contract finishes in 1 year. I'd like to understand what would happen if I exercise these 1000 stock options when I stop working in the USA, would I still need to pay IRS tax on $900K gain and then also deal with taxes in my own country, or if I exercise options while I'm not a tax resident in the USA I'll need to deal only with taxes in my country?

Seems that [residency starting and ending rules](https://www.irs.gov/individuals/international-taxpayers/residency-starting-and-ending-dates) might be relevant for my case.

Comment: Probably need to provide more details. how long have you been in the US, what is your country of citizenship ? A lot of countries have tax treaties so that you aren't taxed twice on the same income.

Comment: The point of question: Does IRS tax in such situations or not. If they do, then tax treaties and what not might make a difference, but if IRS does not tax, then it shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: OK, but you still need to make sure what exactly your status is for the IRS. Are you a resident alien, non-resident alien ? If you work full time in the US (and especially when you have vested stock options), you're likely a resident-alien, which means the same tax burden as US-citizens.

Comment: I'm resident alien, yes. But as I say, when I finish my work contract I'm no longer tax resident and I'm interested what would happen if I exercise options in that year.

Comment: So you want to exercise stock options in 2020 ? (assuming you leave before december 31st 2019 ?) In that case I don't think you'll have to pay taxes in the US.  (assuming you already paid taxes on the value of the options, which would be an employment benefit that is taxed regardless of your residence).... I strongly suggest asking a tax attorney that deals with (non)immigrant tax cases, though.

Comment: I'll definitely will, but before that I'd like to do my own research as well. "assuming you already paid taxes on the value of the options, which would be an employment benefit that is taxed regardless of your residence" - what does that mean? I got stock options grant, and I don't think I was taxed on that.

Comment: @xyious+ option _grant_ is not taxable in US; _exercise_ (if below market, as practically always) is _unless_ the option meets certain requirements to be classified as 'qualified' also called 'incentive' in which case exercise is not taxed but the lower price is used as basis so when you later sell the 'bargain' amount (i.e. the effective benefit) is included in your gain and taxed at capital-gains rates which are lower if you held more than a year. But how this changes if you become nonresident I don't know.

Comment: IOW: contact a tax professional.... After reading some relevant IRS information it would seem that the options you own are not related to your employment (which would mean that they would have had to already be taxed when granted). Investment income generally gets taxed in the country of residence, so there's a bit of confusion there.